# Uploading Data Service with REST when try it got "The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found"

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I'm trying DSS 3.2.1 and upload to server Pais.dbs file, but when try to test the REST resource with GET to url http://www.example.org:9763/services/Pais.HTTPEndpoint/Pais got the error:

```
<soapenv:Reason xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/Pais.HTTPEndpoint/Pais and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.</soapenv:Text>
</soapenv:Reason>
```

Calling through SOAP works like expected.

If I construct the DBS using import the REST resources works. Its something wrong with my .dbs file or maybe a BUG with the way I constructed the .dbs file?

**Pais.dbs**

```
<data name="Pais" serviceNamespace="http://www.example.org/systemx/ds">
<config id="default">
    <property name="carbon_datasource_name">SYSTEMX_DB</property>
</config>
<query id="getPaisByIdQuery" useConfig="default">
    <sql>select id, codigo, nome, sigla, codigoBacen, codigoSiscomex  from Pais where id=:id</sql>
    <param name="id" ordinal="1" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="INTEGER" type="IN"/>
    <result element="resultado" rowName="Pais">
        <element column="id" name="id" xsdType="integer"/>
        <element column="codigo" name="codigo" xsdType="integer"/>
        <element column="nome" name="nome" xsdType="string"/>
        <element column="sigla" name="sigla" xsdType="string"/>
        <element column="codigobacen" name="codigoBacen" xsdType="integer"/>
        <element column="codigosiscomex" name="codigoSiscomex" xsdType="integer"/>
    </result>
</query>
<query id="getAllPaisQuery" useConfig="default">
    <sql>select id, codigo, nome, sigla, codigoBacen, codigoSiscomex  from Pais</sql>
    <result element="resultado" rowName="Pais">
        <element column="id" name="id" xsdType="integer"/>
        <element column="codigo" name="codigo" xsdType="integer"/>
        <element column="nome" name="nome" xsdType="string"/>
        <element column="sigla" name="sigla" xsdType="string"/>
        <element column="codigobacen" name="codigoBacen" xsdType="integer"/>
        <element column="codigosiscomex" name="codigoSiscomex" xsdType="integer"/>
    </result>
</query>
<query id="updatePaisQuery" useConfig="default">
    <sql>update Pais set codigo=:codigo, nome=:nome, sigla=:sigla, codigobacen=:codigoBacen, codigosiscomex=:codigoSiscomex  where id=:id</sql>
    <param name="id" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
    <param name="codigo" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
    <param name="nome" sqlType="STRING"/>
    <param name="sigla" sqlType="STRING"/>
    <param name="codigoBacen" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
    <param name="codigoSiscomex" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
</query>
<query id="createPaisQuery" returnGeneratedKeys="true" useConfig="default">
    <sql>insert into Pais (codigo, nome, sigla, codigoBacen, codigoSiscomex ) values (:codigo, :nome, :sigla, :codigoBacen, :codigoSiscomex )</sql>
    <result element="resultado" rowName="Pais" useColumnNumbers="true">
        <element column="1" name="id" xsdType="integer"/>
    </result>
    <param name="codigo" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
    <param name="nome" sqlType="STRING"/>
    <param name="sigla" sqlType="STRING"/>
    <param name="codigoBacen" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
    <param name="codigoSiscomex" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
</query>
<query id="deletePaisQuery" useConfig="default">
    <sql>delete Pais where id=:id</sql>
    <param name="id" ordinal="1" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="INTEGER" type="IN"/>
</query>
<!--  SOAP -->
<operation name="getPais">
    <call-query href="getPaisByIdQuery">
        <with-param name="id" query-param="id"/>
    </call-query>
</operation>
<operation name="getAllPais">
    <call-query href="getAllPaisQuery"/>
</operation>
<operation name="insertPais">
    <call-query href="createPaisQuery">
        <with-param name="codigo" query-param="codigo"/>
        <with-param name="nome" query-param="nome"/>
        <with-param name="sigla" query-param="sigla"/>
        <with-param name="codigoBacen" query-param="codigoBacen"/>
        <with-param name="codigoSiscomex" query-param="codigoSiscomex"/>
    </call-query>
</operation>
<operation name="updatePais">
    <call-query href="updatePaisQuery">
        <with-param name="id" query-param="id"/>
        <with-param name="codigo" query-param="codigo"/>
        <with-param name="nome" query-param="nome"/>
        <with-param name="sigla" query-param="sigla"/>
        <with-param name="codigoBacen" query-param="codigoBacen"/>
        <with-param name="codigoSiscomex" query-param="codigoSiscomex"/>
    </call-query>
</operation>
<operation name="deletePais">
    <call-query href="deletePaisQuery">
        <with-param name="id" query-param="id"/>
    </call-query>
</operation>
<!--  REST -->
<resource method="GET" path="Pais/{id}">
    <call-query href="getPaisByIdQuery">
        <with-param name="id" query-param="id"/>
    </call-query>
</resource>
<resource method="GET" path="Pais">
    <call-query href="getAllPaisQuery"/>
</resource>
<resource method="POST" path="Pais">
    <call-query href="createPaisQuery">
        <with-param name="codigo" query-param="codigo"/>
        <with-param name="nome" query-param="nome"/>
        <with-param name="sigla" query-param="sigla"/>
        <with-param name="codigoBacen" query-param="codigoBacen"/>
        <with-param name="codigoSiscomex" query-param="codigoSiscomex"/>
    </call-query>
</resource>
<resource method="PUT" path="Pais">
    <call-query href="updatePaisQuery">
        <with-param name="id" query-param="id"/>
        <with-param name="codigo" query-param="codigo"/>
        <with-param name="nome" query-param="nome"/>
        <with-param name="sigla" query-param="sigla"/>
        <with-param name="codigoBacen" query-param="codigoBacen"/>
        <with-param name="codigoSiscomex" query-param="codigoSiscomex"/>
    </call-query>
</resource>
<resource method="DELETE" path="Pais/{id}">
    <call-query href="deletePaisQuery">
        <with-param name="id" query-param="id"/>
    </call-query>
</resource>
```

**DDL for pais table**

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."pais"
(
   id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   codigo int,
   nome varchar(60),
   sigla varchar(3),
   codigobacen int,
   codigosiscomex int
)
;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX pais_pkey ON "public"."pais"(id)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the resource name in simple letters. ie. "pais" instead of "Pais"